# React JS audio does not play

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, audio, playback

I have this react file called "app.js", with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';


const App = () => {
   
   const play = (url) => {
       new Audio(url).play();
   }

   return <>
       <input type="button" value="play" onClick={()=> play("./au.mp3")} />
       <audio src="./au.mp3" id="audio"></audio>
   </>;
}

export default App;
```

Everything is set up correctly, if fact the button does render. However, when I press it, the audio (that is in the same "src" directory as the other files are) does not play.

This is the error:

```
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
   at S (index.js:1)
   at V (index.js:1)
   at index.js:1
   at index.js:1
   at a (index.js:1)
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

Any thoughts on why this might not be working?

Answer (score 1):

So, your example actually works for me, so maybe there is a problem with your audio file? See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-varahamihira-vfnfs?file=/src/App.js), I haven’t changed anything from your code apart from audio url (I’m using a publicly available file from Mozilla’s MDN entry [on Audio object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio))

If you want the audio to be controlled in React Component, you need to use something called "[ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)" (for reference).

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

What you are currently doing is creating a *new*, different audio object inside of your `play` method.

So instead, you can get a handle of your DOM element by using `ref` attribute and `useRef` utility from React and control your audio like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const audioRef = useRef(null);
  const play = (url) => {
    audioRef.current.play();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="button" value="play" onClick={() => play()} />
      <audio
        src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"
        ref={audioRef}
      ></audio>
    </>
  );
};
```

[See the second example working here](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-bird-1w2os?file=/src/App.js:40-395)